# How can I run content script before loading of webpage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to change some dom content such that all input fields value is `""` of a web page before the user can see it .How can I do that? Is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: @wOxxOm I only want to make input fields empty before user can see ?

Comment: I use this `$('input[type="text"]').val("");` in content script . When webpage load completely after sometime (milliseconds) then content script runs and makes input filed empty but i need it before load so that user can not see saved content .

Answer (score 5):

You need a content script that runs on [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), and either of the two methods:

1. MutationObserver ([the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)) but it'll slow down page loading:

   - [How to change the HTML content as it's loading on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334319)
   - [Modify page element as soon as it's loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728162/modify-page-element-as-soon-as-its-loaded)
2. Add a CSS style override to make INPUT text transparent, and when the page is loaded clear the elements and remove the style:

   manifest.json:

   ```js
   "content_scripts": [{
       "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "run_at": "document_start",
       "all_frames": true,
       "js": ["content.js"]
   }],
   ```

   content.js:

   ```js
   // document is empty now so we'll only add the style
   var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
   style.textContent = 'input {color: transparent !important;}';

   // once DOM is ready clear the inputs
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
       for (var i = inputs.length; --i >= 0; ) {
           var input = inputs[i];
           if (input.value) {
               input.value = '';
           }
       }
       style.remove();
   });
   ```

Comment: I wanted to hide some of the elements on my webpage and I was doing them by deleting the elements once they load. After looking at your answer I started using css to set the display none of those elements.

Comment: @rbansal, if hiding is sufficient for you, declare a `css` content script instead of `js` in manifest.json.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: How can I nullify a css rule?  Some website adds a class which changes the color of a heading. I want to write a css rule to nullify all the properties set by the class by my extension.
Example col {color:pink;}, col class is present in some div of the website and I want to nullify all the properties set by the col class through my extension.

Comment: If it was hiding the element .col{display: none !important} was sufficient, but is there a way like .col {  nullify} which will make the future occurring of the col class do not have impact on the properties on the div.

Comment: Please don't use comments for extended discussions. Ask a new question with an [MCVE](/help/mcve).