# Firefox web extension takes a split second to load

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, manifest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a Mozilla Firefox web extension.

My **manifest.json**:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<specific_web_url>"],
      "js":["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"], //file is empty
    "persistent": false
  }
```

Inside my **contentScript.js**:

```
// Remove icon on web page
const iconElement = document.querySelector('vector-icon');
iconElement.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
```

Problem is that everytime I refresh the web page it takes a split second for my extension to load and remove the icon (web page going from default to my web extension style).

I tried adding in manifest.json: `"run_at": "document_start"` and if I do the web extension stops working when I refresh the web page. Anyone knows the issue and how to fix? Thank you in advance.

CSS might not be an option for me because I will scale this and change other things too like colors, background colors and doing all of this in CSS is not scalable, which is why I prefer to use it in js.

Just a guess - is this related to the DOM not being fully loaded and after it executes my script?

Comment: Remove `"js"` and add `"css":["content.css"], "run_at":"document_start"` with `.vector-icon { background:none !important }` inside the css file.

Comment: I don't want to do it in css - thing is I want to modify other things too like colors, etc.

Comment: 1) See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39618852) and those linked inside. 2) You can modify colors in CSS too.